# Azimuth found with Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD much more unstable than Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION

Tags: android, orientation, sensors

I'm doing some augmented reality app and I need the azimuth to compute some object position on the screen. I tried to get orientation data using `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` and since it's deprecated I tried `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`. My problem is that the value obtained with `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` and `SensorManager.getOrientation` is quite unstable compared to `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION`, which makes my object jump a bit on the screen (when not moving the value jump in a range say *[azimuth-5 azimuth+5]* while it hardly moves with `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION`).

**Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION**

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION)
    {
        newAzimuth = (event.values[0] + 360)%360;            
        azimuth = (float) ((newAzimuth * kFilteringFactor) + (azimuth * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)));       
    }
}
```

**Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD**

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            mags = event.values.clone();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accels = event.values.clone();
            break;
    }
    if (mags != null && accels != null) {
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, accels, mags);
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
                SensorManager.AXIS_Z, remappedR);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(remappedR, orientation);
        newAzimuth = (float) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]));
        newAzimuth = (newAzimuth + 360)%360;
        azimuth = (float) (newAzimuth * kFilteringFactor) + (azimuth * (1.0f - kFilteringFactor));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens only when using SensorManager.DELAY_FASTER. With SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME the values are more stable...